# How to refund clients when payment card details aren't stored?

Tags: payment, credit-card

People buy stuff on my site through PayPal or payment card. I need to refund some clients now but I don't have their payment/card/bank details that I could use to do so.

Considering that not storing payment details is common and refunding people is also common, what is the usual solution to deal with this situation?

Comment: I would call them, explain the situation, ask for their bank details, wire the money.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is managing refunds, not programming

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you have the original order details stored, so you'll have their name, transaction reference, payment method, etc.  For PayPal payments, you can issue a refund directly from your PayPal account - just cross reference the order details you have with those stored in PayPal.

For other card payments, what payment processor do you use?  All the main processors have refund functionality built into their APIs.  In my experience, the payment processor (who is PCI compliant) stores the card details and provides you with a unique token that identifies that card.  You then communicate with them using that token, so any payments or refunds can be processed on the right card.

Comment: For card payments I use PayPal Pro. But I've got really nothing logged about payment processed, only information about the customer himself.